# php get the root of the file

Tags: php, include, require

how can i get the root to the main folder? for example i run file in this location :

```
public_html/admin/user/etc/index.php
```

and i want to include file from

```
public_html/includes/user/etc/function.php
```

so i want to do something like this:

```
include(get_first_default_folder().'includes/user/etc/function.php');
```

instead of:

```
include('../../../includes/user/etc/function.php');
```

Comment: add /path/to/public_html to the include_path or create a PUBLIC_HTML constant with the path in your bootstrap

Comment: also, probably, $root = 'public_html'; Many apps need to know the root install dir.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Document root from $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

You can include this line in your index.php file.

```
          include("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}includes/user/etc/function.php");
```

Comment: @Mor This gives a different result in localhost and production server. My production server responce: `/var/www/virtual/{sitename}/www`, Localhost responce: `/Users/{username}/Documents/www`. This is unacceptable to me because I keep identical copies on my site's files locally for testing and upgrading purposes.

Comment: @ZZ-bb i just have faced this problem , thank you for letting me know that! how can i do the same thing on the localhost server?

Comment: @Mor See my answer. I define the sublevel of every file in the beginning of the file and use `include`s like: include("{$root}includes/user/etc/function.php"); Works the same way on every server – a single benefit of little extra manual labor...

Comment: I agree with @ZZ-bb's comment, example I have given this applied if your website running on the root directory. But if your site running on the sub directory of the root directory this will throw error.

Answer (score 2):

I normally do this thusly. `$myDir = dirname(__FILE__);` (or you can use `__DIR__` on PHP v5.3+) is the directory name that the particular file is in. You know where in the hierarchy this is, so you can easily get the base with `$myBaseDir = realpath('../../../'.$mydir)`'.  [Realpath](http://php.net/realpath) expands the path to it's canonical version, not including any symbolic links. Having the full path can also allows for a small speedup when it comes to including or otherwise finding files.

The reason I do that, rather than using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, is that that environment variable probably won't exist if I'm running a script from the command line - it's set by the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

This a bit clumsy approach I guess but it works for me. On the beginning of every file I define a variable `$root`. First level variable is `$root = './'` (this is not required thought), first subfolder is `$root = '../'`, second subfolder is `$root = '../../'` and so forth. `$root` always takes me to the root folder of my site.

When I need to provide a path I just do something like `include("{$root}includes/user/etc/function.php");`

This helped me to get rid of "no such index or file" warnings so I'll stick with it until I find a better way of doing the same thing.

Alternatively you could define a constant for each folder level so you don't have to add `$root` at the top of the every file. (Haven't tested it so I don't know if the following syntax is correct.) Instead you'd do something like:

- {ROOT}includes/user/etc/function.php");` // root level files
- {SUBFOLDER_LEVEL_ONE}includes/user/etc/function.php");` // first subfolder level files

After defining the constants somewhere:

- define("ROOT", "./");
- define("SUBFOLDER_LEVEL_ONE", "../");